# Como verificar se o status de uma medalha está em andamento?

Tags: debate, suporte, medalhas

Percebo que minha futura pratinha de Java está parada há um bom tempo no 362/400, o que me motivou a perguntar, será que existe algum meio de verificar como está o andamento de uma medalha? Para saber se há algum impeditivo para a sua evolução?

Comment: Algo além de ver isto? https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGQzn.png. Faltam 38 *ups* para obter a medalha. O "pontos" ali é tradução errada, são votos positivos.

Comment: Vou ficar de olho, mas a impressão que tenho é que está parado. Um voto positivo em uma resposta minha a uma pergunta com a tag [tag:Java] aproxima esse 362 dos 400?

Comment: Vai para 363 :P

Comment: [Palavra “pontos” deveria ser “votos” em se tratando de medalhas de tag](/q/4637/70)

Comment: @Maniero Eu acho que são "pontos" mesmo, o [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/401803) diz que é o "score" (diferença entre positivos e negativos).

Comment: @hkotsubo então, cada positivo dá 10 pontos (o negativo tira 2 pontos), então não pode ser pontos. Lá não fala em pontos, fala em *ups* e *downs* ("A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag")

Comment: @Maniero Ah tá, é que "score" também pode ser traduzido como "pontuação", mas em português fica ambíguo mesmo (em inglês os pontos são "reputation" então não tem ambiguidade). De qualquer forma também não é só voto positivo, é a diferença entre positivos e negativos... Faltam 38 ups desde que ele não leve nenhum down até lá

Comment: Respondi [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451767/357) e foi para 363 :P está funcionando certinho então, eu que estou lerdo para conseguir a medalha :P